# Input type file + focus + adjacent selector in CSS?

Tags: css, focus, css-selectors

Is there a way to do this in CSS:

```
span{color:black;}
input[type=file]:focus + span{color:blue;}
```

It works with a input[type=text], it works without ":focus", but it doesn't seem to work like this...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some HTML, more info on your desired outcome?

Answer (score 4):

A possible work around for Firefox is using [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) on their parent.

Here is an example:

```css
.file-label > input[type="file"] {
  width: 0;
}
.file-label:focus-within > span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="file-label">
  <input type="file" />
  <span>Select File</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer, No (not cross browser)

This seems to work in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. There are [numerous bugs over the years](https://www.google.com/search?q=input%20%22type=file%22%20%3afocus%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=input%20%22type=file%22%20%3afocus%20mozilla%20bug&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial) being reported about Firefox in conjunction with the `input[type=file]` and `:focus` (or the javascript event) combination. This appears to be one also.

Notice in [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8re/2/), if you click on the ***text*** next to the "Browse" button, it functions to change the `color` on the `span`, but not if you click on the button. As you can see by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8re/21/), it appears the "Browse" button element ends up being "inside" the `input`, and so it apparently is acting as a "child" element of the `input` as far as `:focus` is concerned (`:focus` does not propagate up to parent elements). What is particularly buggy, however, is that `:active` works (which typically is like `:focus`, and does not propagate to parents), as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8re/23/).